# Call an CSS Item with Class AND ID?

Tags: html, css

one quick questions, since I wasn't able to find something yet.

If I have such an HTML Code

```
<ul class="bla">
  ...
</ul>

<ul class="bla" id="blubb">
  ...
</ul>
```

and a CSS Code like

```
.bla {do something}
```

how can I change some attributes in my 2nd  ? I heard the best way is to give the class an unique ID and then overwrite the CSS from the "bla" class. So first question : Is that the best way ?

Second question would be - how do I call it best in CSS ?

just like :

```
.bla {do something}
#blubber {do something else}
```

or is there also another way to be more specific (something like .bla#blubber <-- which wont work just meant - if there is a way to call BOTH elements to be "more specific).

Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: What makes you think `.bla#blubber` won't work?

Comment: how about `.bla:nth-child(2)` ? will select the 2nd element of class .bla

Comment: also, if you set an id you dont even need to mention the class, since id's must be unique, you can just call `#blubb` it will be enough

Comment: `.bla + .bla  {/* do something else*/}` works too `.bla ~.bla` if there's something in between . it will not style the first one, but any behind

Comment: like david said, `.bla#blubber` works fine as well

Comment: Actually it is `#blubb` :) , some extra info doesn't hurt ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem:

You can do that, or even add a new class like this:

```
<ul class="foo bar"></ul>
```

And then reference in the css file as `.foo.bar {...}`.

Second problem:

As @cris9696 suggested, you can use the `#id.class` form, example: http://jsfiddle.net/gKCbc/

Comment: Is it a "better" syntax to use two classes or one class + one ID in that scenario ?

Comment: It depends on the purpose. If you have only item, you can use the ID, but it makes more sense to use a class for styling only.

Comment: If `id` is here, use it and skip the extra class i would say :)

Comment: note that by default, #ID styling overrides .Class styles

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this for the second problem?

```
#id.class{
//css
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Over writing every property my be difficult in some cases. specially when you have a number of properties specified. But what you can do is put the common one's in the more general selector, like in the class selector, and put more specific properties in Id selectors. U can also put default style in the general selector. And for the second question `#idSelct.Class` Works.